# Move queued jobs from one node to other based on node availability in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

What we have done -
We have 20 jobs say A to T, and 5 node machines VM1-VM5. When we take a full run of all jobs/suites on all nodes, jobs gets queued. So in this scenario 5 jobs are running and other 15 are in queue on nodes.
As soon as one job is finished other job in the queue will start executing. This is working fine.

But 
What we want-
In a scenario lets say VM4 is available, while other 4 VMs have a queued jobs, do we have some plugin to move those queued jobs to VM4 for better mileage.

Comment: did you find answer for your question? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try these:
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Scoring+Load+Balancer+plugin

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Least+Load+Plugin

Hope this helps.